# Where is the extra newline coming from?

Tags: c, string

I would like to know where the extra space comes from when my program takes in a few user input and prints them back to stdout. I have a program as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "dbg.h"

#define MAX_DATA 100

int read_string(char **out_string, int max_buffer){
    *out_string = calloc(1, max_buffer + 1);
    check_mem(*out_string);

    char *result = fgets(*out_string, max_buffer, stdin);
    check(result != NULL, "Input error.");

    return 0;

error:
    if(*out_string) free(*out_string);
    *out_string = NULL;
    return -1;
};

int read_int(int *out_int){
    char *input = NULL;
    int rc = read_string(&input, MAX_DATA);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read number.");

    *out_int = atoi(input);
    free(input);
    return 0;

error:
    if(input) free(input);
    return -1;
}

int read_scan(const char *fmt, ...){
    int i = 0; 
    int rc = 0;
    int *out_int = NULL;
    char *out_char = NULL;
    char **out_string = NULL;
    int max_buffer = 0;

    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, fmt);

    for(i = 0; fmt[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(fmt[i] == '%'){
            i++;
            switch(fmt[i]){
                case '\0':
                    sentinel("Invalid, format, you ended with %%.");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    out_int = va_arg(argp, int *);
                    rc = read_int(out_int);
                    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read int.");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    out_char = va_arg(argp, char *);
                    *out_char = fgetc(stdin);
                    break;
                case 's':
                    max_buffer = va_arg(argp, int);
                    out_string = va_arg(argp, char **);
                    rc = read_string(out_string, max_buffer);
                    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read string.");
                    break;
                default:
                    sentinel("Invaid format.");
                }   //end switch
        } 
        else{
            fgetc(stdin);
        }   // end if
        check(!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin), "Input error.");
    } // end for
    va_end(argp);
    return 0;

error:
    va_end(argp);
    return -1;
} // end read_scan

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *first_name = NULL;
    char initial = ' ';
    char *last_name = NULL;
    int age = 0;

    printf("What's your first name? ");
    int rc = read_scan("%s", MAX_DATA, &first_name);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed first name.");

    printf("What's your initial? ");
    rc = read_scan("%c\n", &initial);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed initial.");

    printf("What's your last name? ");
    rc = read_scan("%s", MAX_DATA, &last_name);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed last name.");

    printf("How old are you? ");
    rc = read_scan("%d", &age);

    printf("---- RESULTS ----\n");
    printf("First Name: '%s'", first_name);
    printf("Initial: '%c'\n", initial);
    printf("Last Name: '%s'", last_name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

    free(first_name);
    free(last_name);
    return 0;

error:
    return -1;
}
```

Now I execute the program in shell:

```
%./ex25
What's your first name? a
What's your initial? b
What's your last name? g
How old are you? 11
---- RESULTS ----
First Name: 'a
'Initial: 'b'
Last Name: 'g
'Age: 11
```

Notice that there is a newline after 'g', where does it come from?

EDIT 1: Added the definition of debug macro.

```
#define log_err(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define check(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) {log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error;}
```

EDIT 2: glglgl mentioned that AFAIK the duplicated va_end() in read-scan() is not standard conforming. so what is the standard conforming solution?

Comment: I have some remarks: 1. You have a lot of error handling code (`error:` labels), but you never use them, so they are useless. 2. You don't have to check for non-`NULL`ness before calling `free()`. 3. AFAIK the duplicated `va_end()` in `read-scan()` is not standard conforming. You should solve that in a different way.

Comment: @glglgl, thank you for pointing them out. I did not fully understand your comments. 1. Which one is not used? 2. Again, which line do you refer to?Don't we check NULL pointer after the malloc or similar calls? 3. Could you suggest a standard way? If you can integrate these in your answers, I will take yours and I will also edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @dannycrane All of them. Except that maybe the `check()` is a macro defined in `dbg.h` which somewhere contains a `goto error`. Then my point 1 is pointless and not true. 2. We check for `NULL` after a `malloc()`, that's right. But `if(input) free(input);` can be replaced with a mere `free(input);` because if `input` is `NULL`, we call `free(NULL);` which is perfectly valid and just a NOOP. 3. I will edit into my answer for better readability.

Comment: @glglgl, 1. I put the definitions in the post. Like you said, it contains goto error. 2. Will people worry about NULL pointer dereference vulnerability in C if we dont check NULL right after malloc?

Comment: @dannycrane Again, checking for `NULL` after `malloc()` is ok and necessary, but that's why you have the `check()` calls. But what I am about is the check directly before `free()`, which is redundant. Not wrong, but not necessary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The same newline is after `a`.)

`fgets()` reads a whole line including a terminating newline. That's what you have to compensate for, e. g. by replacing it with a `NUL` character.

---

<strike>Having said that, I would like to extend my comment given under your question. It is not directly related to the problem, thus would better be a comment, but alas, comments are not suitable for appropriately formatted code.</strike>

In the code part

```
    va_end(argp);
    return 0;

error:
    va_end(argp);
    return -1;
```

you have two calls to `va_end(argp);`. This is not allowed by the standard.

Instead, you might want to do

```
    int result = -1;
```

at the top of the function and at the bottom do

```
    result = 0;
error:
    va_end(argp);
    return result;
```

This is the most simple version; you could as well do

```
    int result;
    [...]
    result = 0;
    goto out;
error:
    result = -1;
out:
    va_end(argp);
    return result;
```

Comment: Basic question: why is writing va_end call twice not standard since the code flow will call it once anyway?

Comment: @dannycrane I don't remember where I read it, but AFAIR an implementation is allowed to include some sort of `{` or `}` in these macros, so that each invocation of`va_start()` and `va_copy()` must be "closed" by an appropriate `va_end()`.

Comment: I still dont see the difference between yours and mine implementation since the control flow will result in only one call to va_end in both cases..., but I will take your answer for the other part. Feel free to comment afterwards.

Comment: @dannycrane Obviously, I seem to have misunderstood the relevant part of the standard. It is just about symmetric invocation, not about symmetric occurrence of the macros.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` includes the trailing new line. If you want to strip that off, you have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Read_scan using %s is taking everything on the line entered by the user, including the newline character at the end of the line.  You'll need to trim that off.

Note that you're getting the same newline on the read_scan for first name, just after the 'a' character.

Answer (score 0):

[documentation for fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/): a newline character makes `fgets` stop reading but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string.

so the newline character is included in the first_name and last_name strings because you have read them from input using fgets. a solution can be to remove he last character of the string after getting from input or before printing.